# Linux Numerical Sort Yields An Output That has one line out of place

Tags: linux, shell

I've been trying to sort this file

```
CITTA':SQUADRA:CATEGORIA:NUMERO GIOCATORI:PUNTEGGIO
Civitavecchia:Montalto Montaggi:Serie DM:10:17
Civitavecchia:ASP:U18F:25:24
Tarquinia:Tarquinia:U16F:30:22
Viterbo:VBC Viterbo:U12F:20:18
Montefiascone:Montefiascone:U19M:7:00
```

By the last column, cutting away columns 2 3 and 5.

I've tried doing this

```
cut -f "2 3 5" -d : Citta.txt | sed "s/:/ /g" | (sed -u 1q; sort -nrk 3)
```

But this has been yielding this result:

```
SQUADRA CATEGORIA PUNTEGGIO
ASP U18F 24
Tarquinia U16F 22
VBC Viterbo U12F 18
Montefiascone U19M 00
Montalto Montaggi Serie DM 17
```

Instead of this

```
SQUADRA CATEGORIA PUNTEGGIO
ASP U18F 24
Tarquinia U16F 22
VBC Viterbo U12F 18
Montalto Montaggi Serie DM 17
Montefiascone U19M 00
```

Any help?

Comment: Good question, well formatted.

Comment: Since some of your fields have spaces and you are using spaces as an output delimiter, know that you are taking a legit CSV file (with `:` delimiters) and turning it into something ambiguous -- no longer CSV. If you want to be able to parse this again, you either need to use quoting such as `"VBC Viterbo"` for a field with a space or quote every field or use a deferent delimiter such as a `\t`.

Answer (score 4):

When you use whitespace as the delimiter for sort, multiword entries become more columns. Keep the colon until the last step, use `sort -t` to specify the delimiter:

```
cut -f 2,3,5 -d : Citta.txt | (sed -u 1q; sort -t: -nrk 3) | sed 's/:/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, no pipe:

```
perl -F: -lne '
    BEGIN{ my $h = {} };
    $h->{$F[4]} = "$F[1] $F[2] $F[4]";
    END{ print join "\n", map { $h->{$_} } reverse sort { $a cmp $b } keys %$h }
' file
```

```
SQUADRA CATEGORIA PUNTEGGIO
ASP U18F 24
Tarquinia U16F 22
VBC Viterbo U12F 18
Montalto Montaggi Serie DM 17
Montefiascone U19M 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use `awk` instead of `cut` and `sed` and sub shell:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}
     NR==1{print $2,$3,$5; next}
     {print $2,$3,$5| "sort -t: -nrk 3"}' Citta.txt | sed 's/:/\t/g'
```

Alternatively, you can do a [DSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) type sort:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="\t"}
NR==1{print NR,$2,$3,$5; next}{print $5,$2,$3,$5| "sort -nrk 1"}' Citta.txt | cut -f 2-
```

You could also use Ruby if your CSV is more complex than you present:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
cols=[1,2,4]
data=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:headers=>false, :col_sep => ":", :converters => :numeric}).transpose.
        select.with_index{|_,i| cols.include?(i) }.transpose

puts CSV.generate(:col_sep => "\t"){|csv| 
    csv<<data[0]
    data[1..].sort_by{|row| -row.last}.each{|row| csv<<row }
}' Citta.txt
```

Note both of these use `\t` for an output delimiter between columns. If you use spaces, it is no longer parsable as a CSV file since some of your fields have spaces too. If you *really* want spaces, that is an easy change.

Both print:

```
SQUADRA CATEGORIA   PUNTEGGIO
ASP U18F    24
Tarquinia   U16F    22
VBC Viterbo U12F    18
Montalto Montaggi   Serie DM    17
Montefiascone   U19M    00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you want to stick with GNU awk

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = SUBSEP = OFS = ":"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    }
    NR == 1 { print $2, $3, $5; next }
    { val[$2,$3] = $5 }
    END { for (key in val) print key, val[key] }
' file
```

```
SQUADRA:CATEGORIA:PUNTEGGIO
ASP:U18F:24
Tarquinia:U16F:22
VBC Viterbo:U12F:18
Montalto Montaggi:Serie DM:17
Montefiascone:U19M:00
```

Keep the colon delimiters due to the spaces in the field values.